# javascript if number greater than number

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this javascript function to validate if a number is greater than another number

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["frmOrder"]["txtTotal"].value;
    var y = document.forms["frmOrder"]["totalpoints"].value;

    if (x > y) {
        alert("Sorry, you don't have enough points");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's not working for some reason.

If I do `alert(x)` I get 1300, and `alert(y)` gives 999

This works....

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = 1300;
    var y = 999;

    if (x > y) {
        alert("Sorry, you don't have enough points");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: @user1689607 Comparing numeric strings will still work, i.e `"5" > "2" // true`

Comment: @MattStone: `"1300" > "999"; // false`

Comment: @user1689607 `"user1689607" > "Matt Stone" // true` - I'll have to look up the exact rules for the string conversion. Strange that single digit number strings work correctly.

Comment: @MattStone, string comparison compares the strings letter by letter beginning with the first, `1` is less than `9`, which is why `'1300' < '999'`.

Comment: @MattStone: It's because the `"1"` character comes before the `"9"` character. It does the comparison in the same manner that it compares any other character.

Comment: Ah right, so it's still technically a string (ASCII order) comparison. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should convert them to number before compare.

Try:

```
if (+x > +y) {
  //...
}
```

or

```
if (Number(x) > Number(y)) {
  // ...
}
```

***Note:*** `parseFloat` and `pareseInt`(for compare integer, and you need to specify the **radix**) will give you `NaN` for an empty string, compare with `NaN` will always be `false`, If you don't want to treat empty string be `0`, then you could use them.

Answer (score 3):

You can "cast" to number using the Number constructor..

```
var number = new Number("8"); // 8 number
```

You can also call parseInt builtin function:

```
var number = parseInt("153"); // 153 number
```

Comment: Ooops, using Number as a constructor returns a Number object, and an object is only ever "equal" to itself, so `new Number('7') == new Number('7')` returns `false`. I think you meant to use it as a function, so `Number('7') == Number('7')`. And `parseInt` should always use a radix: `parseInt('153',10)`.

Comment: Ohh!, you are right @RobG about the "=="!! .. I tested these cases and were fine, and I suposed that Number object was always being calling "toString()" implicitly (actually, I think internally its calling valueOf() method):

new Number('725') < new Number('800'); //Outputs true
new Number('91') > new Number('90'); //Outputs true
new Number('7') < new Number('7'); //Outputs false
new Number('7') > new Number('8'); //Outputs false
new Number('8') < new Number('7'); //Outputs false

But for equals, in this way, you need:
new Number('7').valueOf() == new Number('7').valueOf(); //Outputs true

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing strings. JavaScript compares the ASCII code for each character of the string.

To see why you get false, look at the charCodes:

```
"1300".charCodeAt(0);
49
"999".charCodeAt(0);
57
```

The comparison is false because, when comparing the strings, the character codes for 1 is not greater than that of 9.

The fix is to treat the strings as numbers. You can use a number of methods:

```
parseInt(string, radix)
parseInt("1300", 10);
> 1300 - notice the lack of quotes


+"1300"
> 1300


Number("1300")
> 1300
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
var x=parseInt(document.forms["frmOrder"]["txtTotal"].value);
var y=parseInt(document.forms["frmOrder"]["totalpoints"].value);
```

Comment: Specify that you want base 10 with `...]["txtTotal"].value, 10);`