# Comparing numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

So here's my code:

```
var score1 = $(this).attr('data-score1');
var score2 = $(this).attr('data-score2');

if (score1 < score2) {
  // do some
}
if (score2 > score1) {
  // do something else
}
```

Now, this works fine as long as both variables are either both < or both > 100, yet whenever either of those variable is larger than 100 while the other is not the wrong if statement gets triggered. What the hell could be going on here?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You should make an answer.

Comment: Dont know this language, but it probably compares them as strings

Comment: "90" is greater than "100" because "9" has a higher ascii value than "1".

Comment: Just so you know, jQuery isn't a language. You're programming in JavaScript.

Comment: @Diodeus I'm not sure "ascii" is exact here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript if number greater than number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079626/javascript-if-number-greater-than-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `parseInt()`

The attributes will throw up strings.. So when you try to compare them... You are actually comparing

`"100"  > "90"`   and not `100 > 90`  .. Using **parseInt()** with **a radix** should solve your problem..

```
var score1 = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-score1') , 10);
var score2 = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-score2') , 10);

if (score1 < score2) {
  // do some
}
else if (score2 > score1) {
  // do something else
}
```

As @naveen suggested you could do this as well

```
var score1 = +$(this).attr('data-score1');
var score2 = +$(this).attr('data-score2');
```

Comment: dude, `+$(this).attr('data-score1')` will do

Comment: @webarto that would make it score1 >= score2

Comment: @webarto : there could be a tie

Comment: @naveen `parseInt()` is much more readable. If you go for shortness (for some reason), you can use `+` of course.

Comment: Thank you. No ties are possible so I'll make it else.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: whats readable? a unary plus or parsing int with base 10?

Comment: @naveen .. Unary plus can be very useful.. But many people do not know about that operator.. So I think he says parseint is more readable in this case.. I don't think one who has no idea about parseInt to have an idea about unary plus..

Comment: @naveen You might or might not know that in Javascript unary `+` converts to number. If you see `parseInt()`, you already know what it does. If not, you have a function name to search on. I mean, yes, it is very clever that you know this trick, but do you really want to use it in code that other people will read?

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the values as strings. The string "90" begins with `9`, which has an ascii code that is greater than that of `1`.

You can convert it to a number by using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt(score1, 10)
```