# Struggling with making a little number guessing game

Tags: javascript, numbers

How can I make "You got it!" message to pop up when my input is not only 5, but lower or equal to 5?

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("my-input").value == "5") {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
}
```

```html
What is my favorite numbers? 
<input type="text" id="my-input">

<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: use `if(+document.getElementById("my-input").value <= 5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript if number greater than number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079626/javascript-if-number-greater-than-number) and [issue with comparing two numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094299) and [Check if input value is 300 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270245)

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your value to a number using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), and then compare it using `<=`.

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function() {
  if (Number(document.getElementById("my-input").value) <= 5) {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
}
```

```html
What is my favorite numbers? 
<input type="text" id="my-input">

<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the input value which is a string to number before comparing it.

In this case you can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("my-input").value, 10) <= 5) {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
}
```

```html
What is my favorite numbers?
<input type="text" id="my-input">
<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I suggest you to add more explanations about **why** this should be converted from string to int (ie : `"042" < "41" == true`)

Comment: or another example, `"-10" < "-42" == true`

Answer (score 0):

A slight issue with your question is that the type of the input is `text` rather than `number`. You can change the type of the input by doing `<input type=number id="my-input">`.
If you want to keep the type you will have to check if the input is a number.

In either case you will have to convert the value of the input from string to number since numeric operations using strings are wrong most of the time (there are rare specific cases where the outcome is the same). The only difference between using text and number is having to check if the value of the input is valid, which you can do using `isNaN` after the conversion. I usually prefer forcing JavaScript to convert the text by using `- 0` over `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, since it's scricter and will not convert `"123test"` to `123`.

Here is a solution working with number

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("my-input").value - 0 <= 5) {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="my-input">
<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Here is a solution working with text

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var value = document.getElementById("my-input").value - 0;
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    alert("Not a number");
  } else if (value <= 5) {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my-input">
<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you access the **value of `<input>` its a string**. You can't use `>,<,>=,<=` between `strings` you use need to convert it into a number using **`parseInt()`**

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function() {
  let value = parseInt(document.getElementById("my-input").value)
  if (value <= 5) {
    alert("You got it!")
  } else {
    alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
  }
}
```

```html
What is my favorite numbers? 
<input type="text" id="my-input">

<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that u get from input type is string so u need to convert it to number with [ [ParseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) ] methods after that u can compare and everytings will work fine so i think it's better of u

```
let button = document.getElementById("my-button");
let value = document.getElementById("my-input");
button.on('click', function () {
    if (Number(value) <= 5) {
        alert("You got it!")
    } else {
        alert("Opps, wrong number. Please try again.")
    }
});
```

have a nice game